# Merge two branches and keep both chages in sperated dirs

Tags: git

I have two branches, `branch_a` and `branch_b`.

**`branch_a`**:

```
dir_1/a lot of files
```

**`branch_b`**:

```
dir_1/a lot of changes
```

I now think it would be best if instead of just merging, I keep both directories for now.

Desired result:

```
dir_1/a lot of files
dir_2/a lot of changes
```

Of cause I could just copy all the files from `branch_b` into `dir_2`, but that would lose the history. Is there a "git-way" to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to have a separate directory when you can just check out whatever commit you want?

Comment: Initially, I thought, I could replace some code, but now it turns out, it would be best, if I run the replacement in parallel for some time, making the transition more graceful.

Comment: Would you be open to making the folder structure something like `dir_name/merged_files` and `dir_name_legacy/branch_a_files`?

Comment: What you are asking is (a) quite doable, and (b) fairly easy, but, I feel that if you gave a bit more background, there may be a more "standard" solution. That being said, this question is sufficiently clear, so I will answer it. If you decide to ask one with more background, ping me in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would avoid having two copies of your content side-by-side at all. It will make merging the two back together more involved. However, without more information, I can not suggest an alternative, so here goes.

I am assuming that `branch_a` and `branch_b` have some common ancestor commit, but are not simple fast-forwards of each other. If they are, this likely won't work because any attempt to merge will result in a fast-forward, including the rename step.

In `branch_a`, which contains the "legacy" version, move `dir_1` to its intended path:

```
$ git checkout branch_a
$ git mv dir_1 dir_1-legacy
$ git commit -m 'Created separate folder'
```

I would recommend making a separate branch for the merged result, so you can do something like

```
$ git checkout -b branch_transition branch_b
```

If you prefer to just update `branch_b` with the result, just do

```
$ git checkout branch_b
```

In either case, you can now merge in the two folders, preserving the history of each:

```
$ git merge branch_a
CONFLICT (modify/delete): dir_1/XXX deleted in a and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of dir_1/XXX left in tree.
...
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git add dir_1
$ git commit -m 'Merged divergent paths'
```

The step `git add dir_1` is necessary in response to the failed automatic merge, which happens to be exactly what you want under the circumstances.

I would also recommend bumping `branch_a` back one commit, so that any future changes in it do not operate on the `dir_1-legacy` folder:

```
git checkout branch_a
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

**Re-merging**

Once your transition is complete, you can re-merge the two folders using a similar technique. Let's say that you are on `branch_transition`, and would like to merge the two folders together. You can do this by creating a new temporary branch, deleting one version of the folder in each of the branches, renaming one, and merging:

```
git checkout branch_transition
# Create temp branch to hold the legacy code
git checkout -b temp_transition
git rm dir_1
git mv dir_1-legacy dir_1
git commit -m 'Converted legacy to baseline'

# Set up merge on the transition branch
git checkout branch_transition
git rm dir_1-legacy

# Do the merge
git merge --strategy ours temp_transition
git branch -d temp_transition
```

You will need to use `--strategy ours` to get the non-legacy version to trump the legacy one according to my experiments. This is not the same as doing `--strategy recursive -X ours`, which does not work as intended.